# Cant get rid of hover-effect on disabled button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

I have a button that I disable with a checkbox. However, no matter what I try, I can't get the cursor to stop being pointer and go back to default.

(bare with my poorly painted pointer. I don't have a screen capture program to capture the pointer)

When active:

[image]

When inactive:

[image]

Here is some code of interest:

**CSS**

```
.disabledButton {
    color:GrayText;
    cursor:default;
}
```

**ASP.NET markup**

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbLimit" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="cbLimit_Checked" AutoPostBack="true"/>
<asp:Button ID="btnAll" runat="server" Text="All" style="float:right;"/>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#<%=cbLimit.ClientID%>").change(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
        $("#<%=btnAll.ClientID%>").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else {
        $("#<%=btnAll.ClientID%>").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

**C# code behind**

```
protected void cbLimit_Checked(object sender, EventArgs arg)
{
    if ((sender as CheckBox).Checked)
    {
        btnAll.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        btnAll.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

The reason that I set it to disabled in both jQuery and codebehind is that jQuery is much faster, but doesn't really disable some elements, just changes their style.

I've also tried to set class from code behind using:

```
btnAll.CssClass = "disabledButton";
```

to no success.

I've tried to set the class DIRECTLY in the button-tag like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAll" runat="server" CssClass="disabledButton" Text="All" style="float:right;"/>
```

but STILL it looks like image nr 2. How can I get rid of the damn pointer?

Comment: CSS: `.disabledButton { pointer-events: none; }`

Comment: @abhitalks omg thanks! It worked! If you post an answer, I'll accept it. Until then I'll answer my own question

Comment: ok ^^ thought you might want the rep :P

Comment: No problems with rep, you can have that. You may also want to use this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/2bzQJ/) to explain what's going on, to make it a useful answer. (hint: `!important`) Single line answers are not deemed useful and are likely to gain downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An input element of type button has `cursor: default` as browser default, so in order to make the problem appear, there must be some style sheet of yours that changes this. For definiteness, let us assume that it is

```
input[type="button"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Now when you have `<input type=button disabled ...>` and

```
.disabledButton {
  cursor:default;
}
```

the cursor is still `pointer`, since the selector `input[type="button"]` is more specific than the selector `.disabledButton`, by the [cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade) rules.

The fix is to make the selector in the latter rule more specific, e.g.

```
input[type="button"].disabledButton {
  cursor:default;
}
```

Another option is to use `!important`, but it should really be used as last resort only. Yet another is the `pointer-events` property, which works in modern browsers, but [browser support](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events) is still limited.

Answer (score 1):

As abhitalks suggested, I just needed to add `pointer-events:none;` to the css. Another possibility would be to use `!important` after the `cursor:default` as well. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2bzQJ/